# Building a PDF within Java, Export to folder

Tags: java, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using APACHE FOP (v. 1.0) and an XSL-FO template to build a PDF.  What I want to do is export this PDF to an external file (eventually, a server file, but for now, just a folder on my desktop).

The XSL code I know is working fine, but the problem is that it currently only renders a web PDF handled by a servlet (using an .  What I want to create is a stand-alone file.

[Apache FOP XML - XLS-FO generates invalid pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463455/apache-fop-xml-xls-fo-generates-invalid-pdf)

This previous question offers me some guidance, but I can't seem to import FopFactory or MimeConstsants into my code. Is there some prerequisite import I might be missing? Or is our FOP version just less robust than I would hope for?

Code so far (starting with a StringBuffer containing the appropriate xsl-fo code)

```
String stringReadFromReader = buff.toString();

File tmp = new File("[Desktop Directory]" );
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(tmp);

stream.write(stringReadFromReader.getBytes());
stream.close();

StringReader reader = new StringReader(buff.toString());

InputSource isource = new InputSource(reader);
InputSourceDocument isDoc = new InputSourceDocument();

isDoc.setMimeType("application/pdf");
isDoc.setInputSource(isource);
```

The sum of it being: How do I take my raw xsl-FO code and produce a PDF file with it?

Comment: according to [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.xmlgraphics/fop/1.1/org/apache/fop/apps/FopFactory.java/), both `FopFactory` and `MimeConstsants` are in the package `org.apache.fop.apps`. Can you check your dependencies

Comment: See http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/embedding.html#ExampleFO2PDF for a complete example showing how to create a PDF file from a FO file.

Comment: FOP 1.0 is actually what I meant.  Sorry for the confusion there. 

I'm not entirely sure how to check my dependencies.  Nor what would happen if they're not set properly.  

My boss seems to think the first two lines of my XSL code might be incorrect.  Here's the first three, in case this happens to be true. 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <fo:layout-master-set>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had problems with catching error through my IDE about FopFactory and MIME_CONSTANTS before, but in the end it worked regardless of the IDE's claims. There could be a conflicting definition between some of the jars you added to your path as well, but if you are using a stable release of FOP and just added the jars included with it there shouldn't be an issue. As for how to generate a PDF using your java code to call FOP and pass in your xsl-fo file, this should get you started...

```
File xmlfile = new File(xmlFile);
File xsltfile = new File(xslFile);
File pdffile = new File(outDir, outputPDF);
//make your fop factory
final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());


FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();


// Setup output
OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(pdffile);
out = new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(out);

try {
            // Construct fop with desired output format
            Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out);

            // Setup XSLT
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltfile));


            transformer.setParameter("versionParam", "2.0");

            // Setup input for transformations to take effect upon
            Source src = new StreamSource(xmlfile);

            // Generated FO file needs to be passed along to FOP
            Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

            // Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
            transformer.transform(src, res);
   } finally {
            out.close();
   }
```

The above code shows how to set up your factory and feed in your parameters to FOP, where xmlFile, outputPDF, and xslFile are the paths to the files. Hope this helps a little bit...

I strongly recommend checking out the examples provided by Apache for a better understanding of what's going on if you havent already.

Comment: So if I'm getting what you're saying right, the error that it feeds me is a false negative?

Comment: Having just recently tried this, I can confirm that this is not true.  Immediately upon trying to load the class with import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent;, the resource immediately rolled back, and the task was never completed.

Comment: As long as you have added all of the jars included with the FOP distribution to your path, you should only need to import 

import org.apache.fop.apps.FOUserAgent;   
import org.apache.fop.apps.Fop;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory;
import org.apache.fop.apps.MimeConstants;  From FOP, the rest are standard imports

Comment: And if the imports aren't working as they should, how would I check to see if I have the proper jars?

Comment: I've discovered that the problem is that we're using a too-old version of IDE.  So this is technically the correct solution.